# Launch ProgressDialog from

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have a class extends Application where I initialize some libraries needed by my application.

I want to launch a ProgressDialog from this class to notify user what App is doing.

Is possible launch these elements from Application classes??

Thanks

ps. attach my code

```
public class ApplicationLoader extends Application implements InitializeDelegate {

    public static String TAG = "ApplicationLoader";
    private ProgressDialog pd = null;
    private InitializeDelegate initializeDelegate = null;

    @Override
    public Context getApplicationContext() {
        return super.getApplicationContext();
    }




    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // LOAD ANDROID LIBRARY //
        initializeDelegate = this;
        AndroidLibraries androidLibraries = new AndroidLibraries();
        androidLibraries(getApplicationContext(), initializeDelegate);



        try {
            pd = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
            pd.setMessage("Initializing..");
            pd.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

  @Override
    public void initializingResult(InitializinResult initializingResult) {

        Log.i(TAG,""+ initializingResult);

        try {
            if (pd != null) {
                if (pd.isShowing()) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not?

But don't do any heavy stuff in the UI Thread. You may use a [splash screen](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) in conjunction with a progress bar.